# get json array in external file $.getJSON doesnt work

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've this json file:

```
{
"Tools": [
    {
        "Price": 25,
        "Counter": 0,
        "Multi": 4,
        "PriceMult": 1.3,
        "Name": "Cycler",
        "ID": "Tool2"
    },
    {
        "Price": 50,
        "Counter": 0,
        "Multi": 4,
        "PriceMult": 1.3,
        "Name": "Cycler",
        "ID": "Tool3"
    }
]
}
```

If I use getJSON it doesnt work:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/test/json/tool.json", function(data ) {
  alert(data.Tools[0].Price);
});
```

If I use JSON.parse it works:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"Tools" : [{"Price": 25,"Counter": 0,"Multi": 4,"PriceMult": 1.3,"Name": "Cycler","ID": "Tool2"},{"Price": 50,"Counter": 0,"Multi": 4,"PriceMult": 1.3,"Name": "Cycler","ID": "Tool3"}]}');
alert(obj.Tools[0].Price);
```

Why is this so?

---

Edit:

With this code is the Output 25:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/test/json/tool.json", function(data ) {
  alert(data.Price);
});
```

Comment: Most likely because it isn't receiving the file.

Comment: Amy errors thrown on the console?

Comment: If i use no Array in the json file it works! It's only with the json-Array...

Comment: What happens if you go to `http://localhost/test/json/tool.json` in your browser?  I'm assuming that your page is also running on `http://localhost/`, which means it's not a Cross-Domain issue, right?

Comment: `alert(data.Price);` shouldn't work given the structure you posted. Maybe it's a caching issue? Please be more specific than "it does not work". Is the success handler called at all?

Comment: What do you see in your browser's dev tools?  Do you see the AJAX request?  What does it return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody for you help.

The Problem has solved itself. I tried it today with `alert(data.Tools[0].Price);` and it works.

Probably it's a Problem with the Cache.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to access the file via:

```
$.getJSON("test/json/tool.json", function(data ) {
  alert(data.Tools[0].Price);
});
```

I don't know the context root of your localhost server. The example above assumed it was the parent folder of `test`. If it is the `test` folder itself, remove `test` from the url string:

```
$.getJSON("json/tool.json", function(data ) {
  alert(data.Tools[0].Price);
});
```

Comment: What is the context root of your localhost server? If it is the `test` folder, then you should remove `test` from the url above.

Comment: i tryed it with `test/json/tool.json` and `json/tool.json` and even with `tool.json` its not the path

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the status of the $.getJSON call?  This should give the status code indicating any issue with retrieving the file via the ajax request

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :$ how do i do this?